# mock data for local variable Using JUnit

Tags: junit, mockito, junit5

Need help I am very new to JUnit, I want to create a JUnit test case for below method and I want to pass value for `webClient` which is defind as local in below method. So I need to pass value for `webClient`. Could you please guide me that how could I stub value for `webClient`?

```java
@Autowired
@Qualifier("oauthproviders")
Map<String, WebClient> webClientList;

public static Map<String, String> mapClientAccounts = new HashMap<>();
public void callRemoteListenerService(final String uuid, final String userName,
        final boolean mode, File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
    WebClient webClient = webClientList.get(mapClientAccounts.get(userName));
        
    logger.info("The list in webclients are: " + webClientList.keySet().toString());
    
    // Some other code...
}
```

Comment: Where does `webClientList` come from?

Answer (score 0):

First:  "the method below", never "the below method".

Short answer:

1. Create a mock of the "webClientList" thing.
2. Create a mock of the "mapClientAccounts" thing.
3. Create a mock account for the "mapClientAccounts.get(userName)" call to return.
4. Create a mock WebClient for the "webClientList.get" call to return.
5. stub the webClientList.get call to return the mockWebClient;
6. stub the mapClientAccounts.get(userName) call to return the mockAccount

Sample code (based on some assumptions):

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class TestYourClass
{
    private static final String VALUE_USERNAME = "VALUE_USERNAME";

    @InjectMocks
    private YourClass classToTest;

    private UUID liveUUID;
    
    @Mock
    private ClientAccount mockClientAccount;

    @Mock
    private Map<String, ClientAccount> mockClientAccountMap;

    @Mock
    private File mockFile;
    
    @Mock
    private Map<ClientAccount, WebClient> mockWebClientMap;

    @Mock
    private WebClient mockWebClient;

    @BeforeEach
    void beforeEach()
    {
        liveUUID = UUID.randomUUID();
    }

    @Test
    void callRemoteListenerService_blahblahblah()
    {
        doReturn(mockClientAccount).when(mockClientAccountMap).get(VALUE_USERNAME);
        doReturn(mockWebClient).when(mockWebClientMap).get(mockClientAccount);
        
        classToTest.callRemoteListenerService(liveUUID, VALUE_USERNAME, true, mockFile);
        
        ... do the rest.
    }
}
```

Comment: Still Null is coming

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the class containing this method and the 2 maps is called "TestedService", you can try something like this:

```
@Test
void test() {
    // given
    var mockedWebClient = mock(WebClient.class);
    var webClientList = Map.of("test_web_client", mockedWebClient);
    TestedService.mapClientAccounts(Map.of("test_username", "test_web_client"));
    var service = new TestedService(webClientList);
    
    //when
    service.callRemoteListenerService("test_uuid", "test_username");
    
    //then
    ...
}
```

Note that `mapClientAccounts` is static and it will make testing harder. in this case, we are lucky because it is public and we can modify it for the test. Nonetheless, it would be better to use it as non-static and pass it as a constructor argument if possible.